# SSRS:The underlying connection was closed

Tags: reporting-services

I have a problem when viewing SSRS.

The error occurs add line `reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parm);` when I call `GenerateReport()` to view the report in C# win-form progarm.

> Error : The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

It was fine when I view the report through //local_host/ReportServer on I.E address bar.

I’m uing MS Studio 2008, SQL Server 2008
Thanks.

```
public void GenerateReport(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, float dauky, float psls, DateTime kybc)
{
    ReportParameter[] parm = new ReportParameter[5];
    parm[0] = new ReportParameter("fromdate", fromdate.ToShortDateString());
    parm[1] = new ReportParameter("todate", todate.ToShortDateString());
    parm[2] = new ReportParameter("kybc", kybc.ToString());
    parm[3] = new ReportParameter("psls", psls.ToString());
    parm[4] = new ReportParameter("dauky", dauky.ToString());

    this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "domain");
    reportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = true;

    reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("http://localhost:80/ReportServer");


    reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Project1/TEST";
    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
    reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parm);  //error occurs
    reportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
}
```